# Is it possible to move already drawn shapes on the html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

note: i only want to move 1 shape at a time

```
Circle.prototype.create = function(){
    if ( this.canvas === null ){
        throw "Circle has no canvas";
    }
    if (this.canvas.getContext){
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.context.fillStyle = this.color;
        this.context.beginPath();
        this.context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2);
        this.context.closePath();
        this.context.fill();
    }
}
```

This draws a circle, Notice the `context` variable is saved as an object property

i've written this function to move this existing circle using the original circles `context`

```
Circle.prototype.move_to = function(x,y){
    if (this.context === null){
        throw "Circle has no context to move";
    }
    this.x = x; this.y = y;
    this.context.translate(x, y);
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.x,this.y,this.r,0,Math.PI*2);
    this.context.closePath();
    this.context.fill();
}
```

However this just draws yet ANOTHER circle.

How can i get it to move the existing?

WITHOUT CLEARING THE ORIGINAL AND DRAWING ANOTHER!

Comment: You can't, you need (for example) to have a canvas in memory which will be cleared, redrawn and copied to the visible canvas every frame.  Check out - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations

Comment: Take a look at a canvas library like [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is copied from another of my answers but the short answer is you can't do that. What you could do is store the information in an object like so.

```
var rectangle = {x:10,y:20,width:20,height:40};
```

Then you can change any of the values and *redraw* it, you have to clear the canvas first, or at least that portion of the canvas you are redrawing to.

```
//clear the canvas then draw
rectangle.width = 60;
ctx.fillRect(rectangle.x,rectangle.y,rectangle.width,rectangle.height);
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/QrCuj/)**